# Run .exe file as administrator and save credentials

Tags: administrator, domain, runas

I am privileged administrator on domain environment. Domain user to do his work, have to run as administrator and I must type my domain login and password. How can I do that save my credential in secret and user run application without my help?

Comment: Why can't you give permission to users to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

In the Control Panel, open User Accounts and on the left panel, near the top, click on Credentials Manager. Add a generic credentials and see if the user can launch the program without your input.